# Too many arguments on string creation

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I Downloaded a JSON file and then I try to create a string with one of the values of the downloaded dictionary.

The code I'm using:

```
NSMutableDictionary *tempDict = [listaShowsFiltrada objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
 NSLog(@"%@", tempDict);
cell.labelLugar.text = [tempDict objectForKey:@"local"]; //This is working

NSString *stringCidadeEstado = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"%@ - %@", [[tempDict objectForKey:@"cidade"] stringValue], [[tempDict objectForKey:@"estado"] stringValue]]; //This is not working
```

The NSLog:

```
2014-04-27 11:57:46.645  {
    cidade = "S\U00e3o Paulo";
    "cod_agenda" = 15;
    data = "05/05/2014";
    estado = SP;
    "hora_show" = "22:00";
    local = "Teatro Renaissance";
}
2014-04-27 11:57:46.655  {
    cidade = "Belo Horizonte";
    "cod_agenda" = 16;
    data = "06/06/2014";
    estado = MG;
    "hora_show" = "22:00";
    local = "Teatro Sesi Minas";
}
2014-04-27 11:57:46.656 {
    cidade = Curitiba;
    "cod_agenda" = 14;
    data = "14/06/2014";
    estado = PR;
    "hora_show" = "22:00";
    local = "Teatro Regi Vogue";
}
```

The JSON file:

```
[{"cod_agenda":"15","local":"Teatro Renaissance","cidade":"S\u00e3o Paulo","estado":"SP","data":"05\/05\/2014","hora_show":"22:00"},{"cod_agenda":"16","local":"Teatro Sesi Minas","cidade":"Belo Horizonte","estado":"MG","data":"06\/06\/2014","hora_show":"22:00"},{"cod_agenda":"14","local":"Teatro Regi Vogue","cidade":"Curitiba","estado":"PR","data":"14\/06\/2014","hora_show":"22:00"}]
```

The error:

```
Too many arguments to method call, expected 1, have 3.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method initWithString takes only one argument, you want to use initWithFormat:

```
NSString *stringCidadeEstado = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@ - %@", [[tempDict objectForKey:@"cidade"] stringValue], [[tempDict objectForKey:@"estado"] stringValue]];
```